# Why does my model look transparent in EEVEE but look fine in Cycles?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

[image: Image in Eevee]

As you can see in the picture, the model looks like pieces were chopped out of it, and you can see inside. What is going on here and how do I fix it?

Comment: maybe check the material > Settings > Blend Mode, switch to Opaque? Or please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org). Photos are harder to read, because we have to guess if we are looking at a external interference like reflections or smudges or Moiré patterns, hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connection, a software level bug or driver malfunction, or an or actual artifact or issue with the model itself.

Comment: When looking at the material's blend mode, try enabling/disabling "backface culling" and/or "show backface" (if applicable).